# How i can calculate Decimals to real integer?

Tags: c#, .net, integer, decimal

**Hi guys i want have problem with convert any decimals value as real integer
for example 26 / 12 = 2.16. I want the value be 3 not 2.16
How could i do this**

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Math.Ceiling()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(26.0 / 12.0));
```

It rounds off the number to the next number.

Comment: Thanks this function helped me too much :)

Answer (score 0):

Math.Round rounds numbers to the nearest value. It receives the desired number of significant digits. 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-round